# Creating a select all checkbox functionality in a component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table

I have 2 components which are componentA and componentB.

```
componentA - Parent
    -Has one checkbox(selectall)
componentB - Children
    -Has many checkboxes on each row
```

I want a situation where when I check the parent checkbox all the 
children checkboxes are checked and when I uncheck one of the children
the parent is unchecked.

Kindly give some direction on how to do this. I know I have to create a state.
I want to use hooks and functional component.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of achieving this, One easiest way is create a parent component as follows and send the state value as props to children props

```
function Parent() {
  const [allSelected, setAllSelected] = useState(false)

 function handleChange(e) {
  setAllSelected(!allSelected)
 }

return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="checkbox" name="isAllSelected" onChange={handleChange} checked={allSelected}/> Select all
      <CheckboxList isSelected={allSelected}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
function CheckboxList(props) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="1" checked={props.isSelected}/> 
        1
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="2"  checked={props.isSelected}/> 
        2
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This looks simple which is good. I assume the code you showed will exist in the parent component where I have the select All checkbox right? Once this is selected and I pass it as prop to the children, how will i check all the checkboxes for the children? What happens if I also uncheck the parent select all checkbox?

Comment: Yes the above code will be there in the parent component. And to your answer your second question the props which you are sending from parent component will check/uncheck the child component.

function CheckboxList(props) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="1" checked={props.isSelected}/> 
        1
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="2"  checked={props.isSelected}/> 
        2
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}

Comment: Also can you explain this statement setAllSelected(!allSelected) ?

Comment: The state variable allSelected is  a boolean field hence whenever user clicks the checkbox(select all) it will be set the negation of current value for example if the current state value is false when you click on the select all checkbox it will set the value of allSelected to true.

Comment: Again, for handlechange(e), all I am getting is "Parameter e implicitly has an 'any' type. i am using typescript.

Comment: You can remove e from the handlechange method since we are using it. If you want to get rid of that error then you can specify the type in the handlechange method.  convert to handleChange(e: any)

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to have the selectAll onChange event change the value of the all the other boxes

```
const App = () =>{
  const [allBox, changeAllBox] = useState(false);
  const [testOne, changeTestOne] = useState(false);
  const [testTwo, changeTestTwo] = useState(false);
  const [testThree, changeTestThree] = useState(false);
  const selectAll = () =>{
    const newVal = allBox ? false : true;
    changeTestOne(newVal);
    changeTestTwo(newVal);
    changeTestThree(newVal);
    changeAllBox(newVal);
  }
  const changeValue = (e) =>{
    const number = e.currentTarget.id;
    console.log(number)
    switch(number){
      case '1':
        changeTestOne(!testOne)
        break;
      case '2':
        changeTestTwo(!testTwo)
        break;
      case '3':
        changeTestThree(!testThree)
        break;
    }
  }
  return(
    <div>
      <label htmlFor = 'all'>Select All</label>
      <input id = 'all' type = 'checkbox' onChange = {selectAll} checked = {allBox} />
      <ChildCheck label = '1' id ='1' checked = {testOne} onChange = {changeValue} />
      <ChildCheck label = '2' id = '2' checked = {testTwo} onChange = {changeValue}/>
      <ChildCheck label = '3' id = '3' checked = {testThree} onChange = {changeValue}/>
    </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: I started trying this and all I get is Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type. I am using typescript with react